# Issue with classnames library in React (mainly classes application issue, transition not working)

Tags: css, reactjs

I have installed this cool library called [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) in my React project.

I have css modules so this was a good way of making a class work when my state is changed.

This is my component code:

JSX

```
function Text(props) {
    const [text, setText] = useState();
    const handleText = e => {
        setText(e.target.dataset.id - 1);
    };

    const className = classnames(styles.text, {
        [styles["textShown"]]: setText,
    });

    return (
        <section>
            <div onClick={handleText}>
                {props.text.map((text, i) => {
                    return (
                            <div>
                                {answer === i - 1 ? (
                                    <div className={className}>
                                        {text}
                                    </div>
                                ) : null}
                            </div>
                        </>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

CSS module

```
.text {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.text--shown {
    transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
}
```

The problem is that the style is being applied but I cannot see any transition. My intention is for my text to have a transition upon click like [codesandbox FAQs](https://codesandbox.io/docs/faq)

Any idea on how I can achieve this transition with css modules (and no react transition group libraries)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line:

```
[styles["textShown"]]: setText,
```

this just means it will always apply this `styles["textShown"]` class, since setText is always "truthy".

I think what you meant is:

```
[styles["textShown"]]: text,
```

But also, this:

```
.text--shown {
    transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
}
```

It's not forcing any transition, it just means that `if any of the props change, animate with this time, this function and this timeout`. But no prop is actually changed.

Consider this:

```
.text {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
  max-height: 0;
}
.text--shown {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

Here, the `max-height` changes, and that change is animated.

If that does not help, please create a reproducible example in JSFiddle.